# (Eclipse) An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation". java.lang.StackOverflowError in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 4.3 to build a java website. Today, when I started my tomcat server, my Eclipse showed the following error: `An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.index.DiskIndex.readCategoryTable(DiskIndex.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.index.DiskIndex.addQueryResults(DiskIndex.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.index.Index.query(Index.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.TypeDeclarationPattern.queryIn(TypeDeclarationPattern.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.InternalSearchPattern.findIndexMatches(InternalSearchPattern.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.findIndexMatches(MatchLocator.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.search(PatternSearchJob.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.execute(PatternSearchJob.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.searchAllBindingNames(BasicSearchEngine.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.NameLookup.findBindingSearch(NameLookup.java:2168)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.NameLookup.findBinding(NameLookup.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findBinding(SearchableEnvironment.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findBinding(SearchableEnvironment.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2156)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getBinding(Scope.java:1136)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldReference.resolveType(FieldReference.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldReference.resolveType(FieldReference.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve0(LocalDeclaration.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.findVariable(MethodScope.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getLocalBinding(Scope.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve0(LocalDeclaration.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.findVariable(MethodScope.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getLocalBinding(Scope.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve0(LocalDeclaration.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.findVariable(MethodScope.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getLocalBinding(Scope.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve0(LocalDeclaration.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.findVariable(MethodScope.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getLocalBinding(Scope.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve0(LocalDeclaration.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:139)
```

I don't know why this error occurred and how to fix it. So can someone help me?

Comment: [May have already been fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438337); what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: At least show us the stacktrace.  (It should be in the logs.)

Comment: @Makoto I'm using Eclipse 4.3 kepler. I read your link but it did not help me to solve my problem

Comment: @StephenC I have posted the logs above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact same issue in Eclipse Luna.  I had tried lots of solutions, but nothing worked.  I can see in the stack trace that the problem is with JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT), which was the same issue I had even though my project was solely a javascript project.

The solution is to remove the javascript label decoration as shown below by going to Windows - preferences - General - Apperance - Label Decorations and uncheck the Javascript override function indicator:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider 4.4.1 or 4.5M1 versions. faced this problem earlier and found this [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443970). Hope this helps

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.4.1, but the error is still not fix